# Java, save inputstream to file takes hours

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

I'm having trouble with saving the output from a socket. I have an inputstream from a socket and I'm trying to save it to a file. Printing the output works fine i get immediately the output but if I try to save it to a file it takes hours.

I tried different things to speed up the process but it stil takes a long time. Anyone ideas?

```
private InputStream in;

    @Override
    public InputStream sendRequest(Socket socket, String method, String host, String path){
        try {
            pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            pw.println(method.toUpperCase() + " /" +path + " HTTP/1.1");
            pw.println("Host: "+host);
            pw.println();
            pw.flush();

            System.out.println("start saving");
            saveFile(socket.getInputStream(), FileHandling.createPath(host, path));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void saveFile(InputStream in, String path){
        try{
            Files.copy(in, Paths.get(path));
        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's on the other end? Try HTTP 1.0 instead of 1.1 so the peer closes the connection immediately. NB the line terminator in HTTP is `\r\n`, not whatever you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I understand that the socket use HTTP protocol.

In this case I suggest you tu use the Apache HTTP Components [1]: they do the job well.

With [1] you can get the input stream and whit the Apache Commons IO [2] you can write to a file.

Example: https://gist.github.com/alessandro-aglietti/ae1cd5703a56f1bc21b2

[1] http://hc.apache.org/
[2] http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

Comment: Yeah I'm now using Guavo from google code. But I think it has to do something with my design because I created a small program and it wrote the output pretty quick. But thanks for the answer!